# Pass data between two Modules combined in Master App

Tags: ios, swift, dependency-injection

I am working on  Modular Architecture on iOS. Where each feature is an app itself and its completely independent to another app or feature within the Main app in which it's being used.I want to achieve without importing `#import FeatureA` Can i access the public class from Feature A to Main app or between another module which is being embedded in Main app. I am not using SPM currently using frameworks to import all those feature app in Main APp. Please suggest. Thank you.

Comment: Create a protocol or two, make something in each module be the delegate to the other, have the main app wire it up.

Comment: both modules are different how i will delegate them, can you suggest some code for it. Thanks

Comment: Is it an option for you to create another special module for dependency injection, which will act as the registry of dependencies, and make all Feature modules and Main App to link with this new module?

Comment: Yes it could be. but i have been asked not to import any module but treat each framework as a single app. And let them talk with each other via their public interfaces/classes through a mechanism.  Hope i have answered your question.

Comment: Any thought on if we have the same situation in SwiftUI? How we will pass navigation info to another module while we don't have the protocol too. Thanks for any suggestion.